# What Amazon SDK should i use for video ads in FireTv application?

Tags: c#, xamarin, ads, amazon-fire-tv

I am developing a FireTv app where the entire functionality is video playback. I look to monetize solely through pre-roll and mid-roll advertising. Typically I am using Google Ads, but upon researching through the amazon [docs](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/policy-center/fire-tv-advertising.html) for FireTv ads, the following sections are causing some confusion:

> **Inventory Optimization Policy**
>
> Effective as of September 30, 2018 Fire TV Ad-Enabled Apps must
> integrate with Amazon Publisher Services (APS). Your use of APS will
> be subject to the Amazon Publisher Services Agreement (available here
> https://ams.amazon.com/webpublisher/apsmanaged/apsagreement.html).
> Fire TV Ad-Enabled Apps must provide 30% of total advertising
> impressions in the app to Amazon, which 30% will be representative of
> all of the app’s advertising impressions and not exclude or limit
> Amazon’s access to times, programs or categories. Apps will not
> receive payment for the 30% of impressions provided to Amazon.
>
> **Third-Party Ad Network Policy**
>
> Effective April 30th, 2018, Fire TV Ad-Enabled Apps must disclose,
> upon Amazon’s request, which third-party ad networks are used in their
> apps for monetization, measurement or any other purpose. Developers
> must provide this information to Amazon within 30 days of such
> request.
>
> Within six months of Amazon’s request, Fire TV Ad-Enabled Apps must
> remove all third-party ad network monetization software and may only
> access third-party ad networks through Amazon Publisher Services.

My Question now, is what should I do to abide by policy for advertising. I've seen no real answers on using Amazon Publisher Services in a FireTv application, and seeing as the Mobile Ads SDK is [not supported](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/faq-general.html), i'm very unsure what to do.

> Q: Can I use the Amazon Mobile Ads API in my Fire TV app?  The Amazon
> Mobile Ads API is not supported on Fire TV.

What SDK should i use for a Xamarin application for FireTV to serve pre-roll/mid-roll video advertising?

Comment: did you figure out what to do? We are in the same situation.

Comment: @SunilDS Yes, we ended up just going forward with serving ads as normal. Since we're using Xamarin in our project, i've implemented the xamarin wrapper for Exoplayer made by baseflow here:
https://github.com/Baseflow/ExoPlayerXamarin

I just use the internal ImaAdsLoader class and my ad url like normal. I never found any explicit resolution from amazon, but we've gone nearly a year with this approach and no issue at all getting 10+ apps approved on amazon's appstore.

Comment: thank you! We're using Flutter but your answer about serving ads as normal is helpful